# How do partial wildcards in subjectAltName dNSName interact with IDNA domains?

Tags: certificates, sub-domain, wildcard

For instance if I run IDNA encode `bücher.tld` you receive `xn--bcher-kva.tld`. Now imagine the certificate for `https://bücher.tld` has the following field within `subjectAltName`: (`dNSName`, `xn--bcher*.tld`).

Would this mean that the certificate would match `býcher.tld` since it IDNA-encodes to `xn--bcher-qva.tld` or are partial wildcards not allowed for IDNA-encoded domains? Are there any official documents about these two features interacting?

Answer (score 3):

[RFC6125 section 7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-7.2) strongly discourages the use of wildcards inside an IDNA part of the domain name:

```
   o  There is no specification that defines how the wildcard character
      may be embedded within the A-labels or U-labels [IDNA-DEFS] of an
      internationalized domain name [IDNA-PROTO]; as a result,
      implementations are strongly discouraged from including or
      attempting to check for the wildcard character embedded within the
      A-labels or U-labels of an internationalized domain name (e.g.,
      "xn--kcry6tjko*.example.org").  Note, however, that a presented
      domain name identifier MAY contain the wildcard character as long
      as that character occupies the entire left-most label position,
      where all of the remaining labels are valid NR-LDH labels,
      A-labels, or U-labels (e.g., "*.xn--kcry6tjko.example.org").
```

Looking at the source code of OpenSSL and Chromium: they follow this recommendation and have explicit tests for this case. This means that neither  `xn--bcher*.tld` nor `*-kva.tld`  would match `xn--bcher-kva.tld`
I can not find anything about this topic in the [CA browser forum baseline requirements](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/) though.